# Illustrator gradient banding but on the Display?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, gradient

So I was working and everything was ok until a PC crashed which made me re-install windows and adobe products. Until then my gradients were perfect, but now as I try to make one they are full of huge stripes as if I were on a 256 color display from 15 years ago...

I have tried probably everything. I saw things about similar problems on the internet but they all were about the printing job and I have issues on the display.

I am using a Samsung SyncMaster SA300 on 1920x1080 res, full HD over the HDMI. 
Software Adobe CS 5.5 products (mainly Illustrator)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this "gradient" when you're trying to pick a color or is it an actual gradient on your page? Does everything outside of photoshop look correct?

Comment: sounds like a display driver issue. This should be migrated to superuser.

Comment: Is this problem specific to Adobe apps or is it system wide?

Comment: Thanks everybody - about the problem: yes it happens only in Illustrator/Phtoshop/etc in gradients. My system looks ok nothing wrong with any other applications.

Comment: REMOVED by me: redundant

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go out on a limb and say you are probably having an opengl driver issue. Try updating your video drivers and/or disabling opengl drawing in the preferences.

Comment: I think I'd crawl out on the same limb on this one, although there's a side twig I'd also explore. :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely try horatio's suggestion if the following doesn't change anything:

Delete the existing preference files for the Adobe applications you're seeing problems with. For Photoshop and Illustrator, just hold down Ctl-Alt-Shift while the application launches.